# How do I make a custom publish button for a page and make it do the same as the ribbon publish button?

Tags: ribbon, publishing, application-pages

How do I make a custom publish button for a page and make it do the same as the ribbon publish button? We have a request from the customer to make a simple page that should have a custom publish button in addition to the publish button in the Ribbon (see picture). I have searched google and tried, but could not find any solution to this.

A possible solution could involve the SPContext.Current.File.Publish("myComment"); but this demands a lot of custom handling if there is a workflow?

[image: Publishing button]

Answer (score 5):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        var pageStateGroupPublishValue = SP.Ribbon.PageState.PageStateCommands.pageStateGroupSubmitForApproval;
        SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().executeRootCommand(pageStateGroupPublishValue, window.g_CUIcommandProperties, { CommandId: pageStateGroupPublishValue }, null);
    }, "sp.ribbon.js");
```

Answer (score 2):

@Andrey Markeev, Looks like `window.g_CUIcommandProperties` is `undefined` on some pages. This code worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Custom_Submit(command)
    {
        SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.showStateChangeDialog(command, SP.Ribbon.PageState.ImportedNativeData.CommandHandlers[command]);
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:Custom_Submit('PageStateGroupPublish'); return false;" value="Publish" id="btnPublish"></input>
```