# need to click submit/publish button on ribbon via HTML button

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, ribbon, html

I have one HTML button to to submit on one custom page layout.
I want to to submit or publish this page on this HTML button click.
I tried with binding it with ribbon button onclick using jquery. But its not working. Anybody has any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery to simulate clicking the ribbon button? `$("#customButtonID").click(function(){$("#ribbonButtonID").click()});`

Comment: yes... but it does not work. in this case. It works for other buttons on the page but not for buttons on the ribbon...!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/52877/35604:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Custom_Submit(command)
    {
        SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.showStateChangeDialog(command, SP.Ribbon.PageState.ImportedNativeData.CommandHandlers[command]);
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:Custom_Submit('PageStateGroupPublish'); return false;" value="Publish" id="btnPublish"></input>
```

And quite the same for "Submit for approval" action, only change `PageStateGroupPublish` to `PageStateGroupSubmitForApproval`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Custom_Submit(command)
    {
        SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.showStateChangeDialog(command, SP.Ribbon.PageState.ImportedNativeData.CommandHandlers[command]);
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:Custom_Submit('PageStateGroupSubmitForApproval'); return false;" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"></input>
```

Comment: its working for publish. I want to get it worked for Submit.

Comment: I edited my answer to add this case.

Comment: Do you have any idea about command ID for schedule button on the ribbon ? I checked that namespace but looks like its not listed there..! Please let me know if you have any idea about it. I have to have one custom button to schedule publication start date.!

Comment: Poping-up the Schedule window is another story, not related to the `command handlers` thing. Please, post a new question, and I'll try to find and answer it (add a comment here so I know).

Comment: Found it: to open the Schedule dialog, simply call `Pub.Ribbon.PubCommands.schedule();`.

Comment: Hi Evaiste,
Hope you are doing good.. I have one question. I have to trigger alert button on the ribbon from the html link... do you have any idea about it?